# Css Rules in UserControls

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, user-controls

I'm sorry if the title of this question is quite vague...

I have a Web Application composed by a MasterPage in wich I include all my css and js files and any other page will be loaded into the content of the MasterPage.

In a page I call another page via javascript with this call:

```
  <script type=text/javascript>window.open('ApriOrdine.aspx?ID=B300&MODE=UPD',null,'scrollbars=1')</script>
```

the page ApriOrdine.aspx contains 2 UserControls. I have a problem with css rules, I cannot set the padding using css rules written in css external files.

This is the whole code of my ApriOrdine.aspx:

```
 <%@ Page Title="Orders" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ApriOrdine.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.ApriOrdine" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

 <%@ Register TagPrefix="UC" TagName="UserControlCom" Src="~/Commessa.ascx" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="UC" TagName="UserControlCli" Src="~/Cliente.ascx" %>
 <head runat="server">
 <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
<body>
  <form runat="server">
    <div class="ApriOrdine">
        <div>
            <UC:UserControlCom runat="server" ID="ucCommessa" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <UC:UserControlCli runat="server" ID="ucCliente" />
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
</body>
```

As you can see, the css.css file it's included behind head tags.

The problem in that if I write this css rule in my css.css like this it doesn't works.

```
 .ApriOrdine
 {
      padding:50px;
 }
```

Instead, if I assign the padding using style attributes to the div it works perfectly...

```
 <div class="ApriOrdine" style = "padding:50px;">
```

EDIT

this is my [complete source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouf249gbp67c40z/codice.txt?dl=0)

and this is the [css](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqa1nndoccb7jra/css.txt?dl=0)

So, what is wrong here? Please help me, thanks!
If you need some more details please ask me!

Comment: Have you taken a look in the browser developer tools (chrome right click on the element and inspect or f12 on ie).  That is usually the best place to start - you can see the css applied to the html, if the css is actually loaded etc.

Comment: @Symeon: yes, the css rules is not loaded when I inspect my element .ApriOrdine

Comment: So maybe you are getting a 404 error for the css - can you check the network tab in the dev tools

Comment: @Symeon It's really strange because other rules are loaded.... :S

Comment: maybe there is a syntax error in the css above, so it is not being recognised.  can you post more of the css ?

Comment: I cannot find ApriOrdine in the css anywhere ?

Comment: @Symeon excuse me, in my application I had the rules but I forgotted to paste them in css.txt file :S now is updated

Comment: When i run up that html and css the div .ApriOrdine has a padding of 50 px all around it.  ?   See here - http://jsfiddle.net/ofzt6bh7/   So if it is not working on yours, one of your other CSS's must override the padding, or the javascript is changing the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason i see is that your reference to the css is not good. 
I don't know the structure of your project but i guess the master page is not at the same place as your .aspx page. So if you copy and paste the reference from the master page it's not working in the .aspx page cause the structure is not the same.

An other thing you could do is once the page is loaded, open the source code of the page and look at the reference generated in the page and make sure the path is good.

Hope this help.